# Can't get nodejs : createReadStream to work

Tags: node.js

I want to read a .csv. The consensus seems to be to do something like this:

```
   const myCsv = "./my.csv";

    // Throws exception if file doesn't exist
    // File permissions are also 777 (just to figure this out)
    fs.statSync(myCsv);     

    fs.createReadStream(myCsv)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", () => console.log('got data')
      .on("end", () => console.log('the end')
      .on("error", () => console.log('error')
);
```

When I run this, none of the console.log() statements execute, and no errors/warnings.

Indeed, to try to understand what's going on, I run the following test case:

```
 (() => {
      const readStream = fs.createReadStream(myCsv);

      readStream.on("open", () => {
        console.log("open");
      });

      readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
        console.log("data");
      });

      readStream.on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("error");
        console.log(err);
      });

      readStream.on("end", () => {
        console.log("end");
      });

      readStream.on("finish", () => {
        console.log("finish");
      });
    })();
```

After fs.createReadStream(), readStream.fd = null (that can't be good), and none of the console statements executes.

NodeJs version = v16.19.0, and I'm running it on Ubuntu 22.04.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: `fs.createReadStream()` is asynchronous, so `.fd` will not have a value until after the `open` event occurs.  You are probably looking for the `.fd` value too soon.

Comment: When I run your last block of code, it works just fine for me.  It produces output that shows `open`, then `data`, then `end`.  So for me, your question is not yet showing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Since you were able to run my 'last block of code', isn't that a minimal reproducible example? So then the question is why it would work on your machine but not mine: I'm not seeing ANY of the console.logs(), neither 'open', nor 'data' nor 'end'.

Comment: Except, that last block of code doesn't illustrate any problem.  It works just fine.  So, that's not **reproducible**.  It doesn't reproduce a problem.

Comment: Well, it doesn't run on mine. Which tells me my machine is corrupted or something like that. And that tells me which haystack to look in -- which is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting `fs` from?  Can you show the WHOLE code that you are running, including any imports?  And, why are you wrapping it in an IIFE?  There is no reason to do that.